# Singular-value Decomposition explanation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently studying Singular-Value Decomposition. But I got stuck with the last part of it.

The last part explains if a m * k matrix A is apporximated by B, having the same dimension but lower rank, the sum of squared differences is explained in the posted image.

I am still not that deep in Linear Algebra, so if you understand this part, can you please explain in plainer English?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given a matrix $X$ of dimensions $p\times q$, the trace of $X\cdot X'$ is the sum of squared elements of $X$.

To see why, compute diagonal elements. Notice $X\cdot X'$ has dimension $p\times p$, and:

$$x_{ii}=\sum_{j=1}^q x_{ij} x_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^q x_{ij}^2$$

In the first sum, notice that the element $i,j$ of $X$ is $x_{ij}$, and the element $j,i$ of $X'$ is also $x_{ij}$. (*)

Thus

$$\mathrm{tr} \; \left[X\cdot X'\right]=\sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{j=1}^q x_{ij}^2$$

Now, if you apply this to $X=A-B$, then

$$\sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{j=1}^q (a_{ij}-b_{ij})^2=\mathrm{tr}\; \left[(A-B)(A-B)'\right]$$

---

(*) The product of matrices $A$ ($p\times q$) and $B$ ($q \times p$) with elements $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$, is the matrix $C$ ($p \times p$) with

$$c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^q a_{ik}b_{kj}$$

Hence the diagonal elements are

$$c_{ii}=\sum_{k=1}^q a_{ik}b_{ki}=\sum_{j=1}^q a_{ij}b_{ji}$$

And here $A=X$ and $B=X'$, thus $a_{ij}=x_{ij}$, and $b_{ji}=x_{ij}$.